# Older version of files and deleted files appearing on github

Tags: git, github

I am new to version control. Whenever I import a repository to GitHub, older version of files and the files that I have deleted also appear on GitHub page.

What can I do?

[image: ~ is appearing in front of these files]
`~` is appearing in front of those files.

Answer (score 2):

They currently have some latency issues and database problems. See https://status.github.com/ and https://status.github.com/messages

This should hopefully be fixed soon.

Comment: Now current status on their site is:Everything operating normally.But my problem is not fixed. This the link to my repo: https://github.com/ishan-nitj/movie-search-engine/tree/master/templates